# Where are the TweetDeck settings-files located in (ubuntu-) linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, twitter

i'm running Windows as well as Ubuntu and like to sync both tweetdeck installations via dropbox.

Therefore i need to locate two files:

1. td_26_[username].db
2. preferences_[username].xml

I found them on windows under the folder c:\Users[account]\AppData\Roaming\TweetDeckFast.[random string]\Local Store\
But i can't find them on my ubuntu installation.

Does anyone know where these files are located?

Best Regards 
Philipp

Comment: ~/.appdata/TweetDeckFast.[long string, probably user-specific].1 ?

Answer (score 2):

making my comment above an answer: try

```
~/.appdata/TweetDeckFast.[long string, probably user-specific].1
```